# Empty arrays returned in Ruby recursion

Tags: arrays, ruby, recursion

I am trying to solve a recursion problem.

Code:

```
def divide(array)
  half = array.length/2
  return array if array.length == 1
  print ary1 = divide(array[0..half - 1])
  print ary2 = divide(array[half..-1])
  merge(ary1, ary2)
end
def merge(ary1, ary2)
  sorted = []
end

divide([10,9,8,-300,250,1,7,6,5,4,3,2])
```

If I don't comment out the `sorted` variable, it returns a few blank arrays mixed with numbers:

```
[10][9][8][][][-300][250][1][][][][7][6][5][][][4][3][2][][][]
```

I have no idea why naming a variable (but not calling it) would result in a different output than otherwise. Any insight into this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby functions which don't have an explicit return statement return the last evaluated expression.  In your case that's `sorted = []` which evaluates to just `[]`.  So `merge` will always return `[]`.

A call to `merge` is the last expression in `divide`, so it too will return `[]` if it reaches that point.

For this reason, and for others, it's a good idea to always end functions with a return statement.  Even if you intend to return the last evaluated expression, it makes your intent clear.  If you intend to return nothing, just write `return`.